# Allow PHP file_get_contents but restrict all other public access to directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, permissions

I have a directory of PDF files that nobody should be able to access, however the directory must remain in the webroot. I use `file_get_contents` to access the PDF files for use in my PHP scripts (ie. base64_encoding and protected downloads).

I have tried different combinations of the following in my .htaccess located inside the directory, but it either restricts all access, causing the PHP script to fail, or allows full access for all users.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from localhost
satisfy any
```

All PDF files have `-rw-r--r--` permissions and are owned by `apache` user.

What should I put in my .htaccess file to prevent users from accessing the directory but allowing PHP scripts access?

Comment: If `file_get_contents` reads over the filesystem, your apache rules won't make PHP fail. It's something else.

Comment: Why must the directory remain in the webroot? `file_get_contents` should still work if they are elsewhere.

Comment: Is file_get_contents using http?

Comment: is PHP open_basedir in use?

Comment: Does file_get_contents make a http request? Because in that case it would be blocked by the apache rules. Is there a way that I can avoid making an http request?

Comment: If you're doing this: `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/pdfs/mypdf.pdf')` then it's using http. If you're doing this: `file_get_contents('/public_html/pdfs/mypdf.pdf')` then it isn't.  Denying all in htaccess and using file_get_contents on a local path would meet your requirements as long as your code and pdfs resides on the same file system. I'm not clear from your description if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you @Vrac! That solved it. Do you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this: `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/pdfs/mypdf.pdf')` then it's using http. If you're doing this: `file_get_contents('/public_html/pdfs/mypdf.pdf')` then it isn't. Denying all in htaccess and using file_get_contents on a local path would meet your requirements as long as your code and pdfs reside on the same file system. (Moved from comments...)